# Five second wait in activemq cms MessageProducer.send with zookeeper

Tags: activemq-classic, redhat, apache-zookeeper

I'm testing [ActiveMQ 5.9.0 with Replicated LevelDB](http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html).

Running against a standalone ActiveMQ with a local LevelDB store, each `producer.send(message)` call takes about 1 ms. With my replicated setup with 3 zookeepers and 3 activemq brokers, `producer.send(message)` takes slightly more than 5 seconds to return! This happens even with `sync="local_mem"` in `<replicatedLevelDB ... >`. It's always just above 5 seconds, so there seems to be some strange wait/timeout involved.

Does this ring a bell?

It doesn't matter if I set brokerurl to `failover:(<all three brokers>)` or just `tcp://brokerX`, where brokerX is in the replicated LevelDB setup. There is no noticable delay sending messages in the brokerX web ui (hawtio). If I change to `tcp://brokerY`, where broker is an otherwise identical broker with `<persistenceAdapter ...>` set to `<levelDB...>` instead of `<replicatedLevelDB...>`, we're down at 1 ms per send.

Changing zookeeper tickTime etc makes no difference.

Debug log below. As you see, 5 seconds between "sent to queue", but zookeeper ping is quick.

```
2014-02-19 10:45:34,719 | DEBUG | Handling request for path /jolokia | io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter | qtp1217711018-227
2014-02-19 10:45:34,724 | DEBUG | localhost Message ID:<hostname>-57776-1392803129562-0:0:1:1:2 sent to queue://IO_stab_test_Q | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<ip address>:54727@61616
2014-02-19 10:45:34,725 | DEBUG | IO_stab_test_Q toPageIn: 1, Inflight: 1, pagedInMessages.size 1, enqueueCount: 27, dequeueCount: 25 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-20
2014-02-19 10:45:34,731 | DEBUG | Handling request for path /jolokia | io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter | qtp1217711018-222
2014-02-19 10:45:34,735 | DEBUG | Got ping response for sessionid: 0x244457fceb80003 after 0ms | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(<hostname>:2181)
2014-02-19 10:45:34,867 | DEBUG | Handling request for path /jolokia | io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter | qtp1217711018-222
2014-02-19 10:45:35,403 | DEBUG | Got ping response for sessionid: 0x244457fceb80003 after 0ms | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(<hostname>:2181)
2014-02-19 10:45:35,634 | DEBUG | Handling request for path /jolokia | io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter | qtp1217711018-227
2014-02-19 10:45:36,071 | DEBUG | Got ping response for sessionid: 0x244457fceb80003 after 0ms | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(<hostname>:2181)
2014-02-19 10:45:36,740 | DEBUG | Got ping response for sessionid: 0x244457fceb80003 after 0ms | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(<hostname>:2181)
2014-02-19 10:45:37,410 | DEBUG | Got ping response for sessionid: 0x244457fceb80003 after 0ms | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(<hostname>:2181)
2014-02-19 10:45:38,088 | DEBUG | Got ping response for sessionid: 0x244457fceb80003 after 8ms | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(<hostname>:2181)
2014-02-19 10:45:38,623 | DEBUG | Handling request for path /jolokia | io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter | qtp1217711018-222
2014-02-19 10:45:38,750 | DEBUG | Got ping response for sessionid: 0x244457fceb80003 after 0ms | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(<hostname>:2181)
2014-02-19 10:45:39,420 | DEBUG | Got ping response for sessionid: 0x244457fceb80003 after 0ms | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(<hostname>:2181)
2014-02-19 10:45:39,735 | DEBUG | localhost Message ID:<hostname>-57776-1392803129562-0:0:1:1:3 sent to queue://IO_stab_test_Q | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<ip address>:54727@61616
2014-02-19 10:45:39,737 | DEBUG | IO_stab_test_Q toPageIn: 1, Inflight: 2, pagedInMessages.size 2, enqueueCount: 28, dequeueCount: 25 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-24
2014-02-19 10:45:40,090 | DEBUG | Got ping response for sessionid: 0x244457fceb80003 after 0ms | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(<hostname>:2181)
```

Comment: I would first test against a 5.10-SNAPSHOT as there we a ton of fixes for LevelDB since 5.9.0 was released.

Comment: Moving from RELEASE to SNAPSHOT is not always an option. This delay is negatively impacting us as well, but we can't run SNAPSHOT in production.

Answer (score 1):

Set queuePrefetch=0.

Some background on our situation...

Our message sizes are fairly small (<1kb xml) but our consumers vary from fast (<1 sec) to slow (10+ hours). Previously we had set prefetch=1, but even this would cause issues for us when a slow message is being worked and another message gets prefetched behind it.

We had noticed that our fast messages would often finish processing before the producer even gets the ack! We found that the producer.send() method was taking +5 seconds (exactly) to what we expect. That is what lead me to find this question.

Anyway, the solution for us was to set prefetch=0. This eliminated the 5 second delay completely for us, and resolved the other issue for us as well.